# ViewModel properties null on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I need two models in my view, so I created `ViewModel` that combines them. That is on getting method. But on the Post, my `input type=submit` is returning `ViewModel`, but values of properties inside are null. Any advice?

These are my actions for Get and Post

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Report(int id)
    {
        using (SkolskaBibliotekaDBModel db = new SkolskaBibliotekaDBModel())
        {
            ReportZaPrikaz RZP = new ReportZaPrikaz();

            var komentar = db.Komentar.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KomentarID == id);

            RZP.kzp = new KomentarZaPrikaz()
            {
                KomentarID = komentar.KomentarID,
                KomentarText = komentar.KomentarText,
                KorisnikID = komentar.KorisnikID,
                Reported = komentar.Reported,
                VremeKomentara = komentar.VremeKomentara,
                Ime = komentar.Korisnik.Ime,
                Prezime = komentar.Korisnik.Prezime,
                PicPath = komentar.Korisnik.PicPath,
                VoteUp = komentar.VoteUp,
                VoteDown = komentar.VoteDown
            };

            RZP.report = db.PrijavaKomentara.Create();

            return View("Report",RZP);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Report(ReportZaPrikaz RZP)
    {
        using (SkolskaBibliotekaDBModel db = new SkolskaBibliotekaDBModel())
        {
            db.PrijavaKomentara.Add(RZP.report);
            db.SaveChanges();  
        }
    }
```

this is my viewmodel:

```
namespace SkolskaBiblioteka.ViewModels
{
    public class ReportZaPrikaz
    {

        public KomentarZaPrikaz kzp;
        public PrijavaKomentara report;

    }
}
```

and this is my view:

```
@model SkolskaBiblioteka.ViewModels.ReportZaPrikaz

@using SkolskaBiblioteka.ViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Пријава коментара";
}

<div class="container">
@Html.Partial("_Komentar", Model.kzp)

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PrijavaKomentara</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @{
            Model.report.KorisnikId = ((KorisnikZaPrikaz)Session["Korisnik"]).KorisnikId;
        }
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.report.KorisnikId)

        @{
            Model.report.KomentarId = Model.kzp.KomentarID;
        }
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.report.KomentarId)

        @{
            Model.report.VremePrijave = DateTime.Now;
        }
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.report.VremePrijave)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.report.Tekst, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.report.Tekst, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

These conditions show up when I hit submit button.
[image: my code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default model-binder would not bind *fields*. Try to use *properties* instead:

```
public class ReportZaPrikaz
{
    public KomentarZaPrikaz kzp { get; set; }
    public PrijavaKomentara report { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You were couple of seconds faster than me. I wrote exactly the same answer   +1

Comment: Dear god. -.- It was really late last night. Thanks.